# AlertDialog can't get context in custom adapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-alertdialog, android-context

I'm trying to show a AlertDialog when I press a button from a ViewHolder from my adapter. But when I launch this crash with the next message.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: cl.abitsoft.todotick, PID: 4172
>       android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:798)

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowModel> implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<RowModel> DataSet;
    Context context;

    private static class ViewHolder {
        [...]
    }

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<RowModel> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item_main, data);
        this.DataSet = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        final Object object = getItem(position);

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.list_delete_button:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.show();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        [...]
    }

}
```

EDIT: Added MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {

    ListView listview;
    private CustomAdapter adapter;

    private Button no, button_accept;
    private EditText edittext_title;
    private Spinner spinner_classes;

    private RowModel rowModel;

    private ArrayList<RowModel> row_models;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(this);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Se inicializan las variables
        edittext_title = findViewById(R.id.main_edittext_title);
        spinner_classes = findViewById(R.id.main_spinner_classes);
        button_accept = findViewById(R.id.main_button_accept);
        listview = findViewById(R.id.main_listview);
        row_models = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(row_models, getApplicationContext());
        // AL ListView se le asigna el Adapter con el tipo de objeto que usaremos
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Creamos un arreglo del tipo String con las variables para el Spinner
        String[] values = {"Pagar", "Cobrar", "Llamar", "Pedir", "Comprar", "Revisar", "Otro"};
        // Agregamos las variables a nuestro Spinner
        spinner_classes.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_main, values));
        // Habilitamos el click en nuestro boton
        button_accept.setOnClickListener(this);

        loadRows();
    }
    [...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the context that you have declared globally

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

and change the following line to

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(row_models, getApplicationContext());
```

to

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(row_models, this);
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: yea, that's work perfectly, but can you explain the difference between the `getContext` and `this`?

Comment: getApplicationContext() returns the context of the whole application as per its name meanwhile this was referring to your current Activity i.e MainActivity in your case on which you want the dialog to pop up.

Comment: @ChristopherVivarVivar please mark the answer (correct) so other facing the same issue can easily get to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Make this 3 changes to resolve your problem,

1. first pass "this" in CustomAdapter.

   ```
   adapter = new CustomAdapter(row_models,this);
   ```
2. get Activity in CustomAdapter.

   ```
   public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<RowModel> data, Activity activity) {
   super(context, R.layout.list_item_main, data);
   this.DataSet = data;
   this.context = context;
   }
   ```
3. Create AlertDialoge using "activity".

   ```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
   ```

Comment: only with the first pass works, 2 and 3 isn't necessary, this :)

Comment: 2 & 3 also needed because if you  mentioned Context instead of Activity  then your problem remain same!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `Context` from your `View` like this:

```
@Override public void onClick(View v) { 
    int position = (Integer) v.getTag(); 
    final Object object = getItem(position); 

    switch (v.getId()) { 
        case R.id.list_delete_button: 
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()); 
            builder.show();
            break; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: the problem persist. I try, v.getContext(), MainActivity.getApplicationContext(), context, getContext() and all time is the same problem

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that you already passed in a context through your constructor. It also looks like the crash you're getting isn't related to getting the context, but that the Activity that hosts the adapter doesn't exist anymore. Are you holding onto the adapter even after the activity has been destroyed, such as after a rotation change or etc?

Comment: Now I added the MainActivity

Comment: Why are you adding this into my answer instead of your question?

Comment: my bad, now I fix it

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use either `Activity` instance or can TypeCast `Context` to `Activity` like this following:

`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);`

or

`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder((Activity)context);`

and Where you are showing `AlertDialog` then do something like this

```
if(!((Activity)context).isFinishing())
{
    builder.show(); 
}
```

You will not get that exception

Comment: I try this, but not work, I need give the context in the *MainActivity* to adapter with `this`

Comment: @ChristopherVivarVivar, I have updated the answer, check If your issue not solved.